# How should I completely mirror a server user rsync, without using root password?

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

I use rsync to mirror a remote server. It is said that using a root password with rsync is dangerous, so I created a special rsync user. It seems to work fine, but cannot copy some files because of file permissions. I want to mirror whole directories for backup, and I guess this cannot be done without using root password, I mean if root does not give permissions on a specific files, no other account can read them. Is there other solutions and why shouldn't I use root account in rsync (I only do one way copying, that does not effect source).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the whole server, then yes, you need root. However, instead of "pulling" (where you have a cron on your local server that does "rsync remote local"), can you possibly do it by "push" (where you have a cron on the remote server that does "rsync local remote"?) In this case, you won't need to configure the remote server to accept inbound root connections.

Comment: thanks, I think pushing is the right solution. Which is also secure for remote server.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use an ssh login as root, but using ssh pubkey authentication instead of a password. In general, pubkeys are the wya to go, if you want to automate this later.

You'll want to look into the `PermitRootLogin` [sshd_config](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd_config) setting, in particular the `without-password` setting or, if you want to get even more sophisticated and (probably) secure, the `forced-commands-only` setting.

Some useful links:

- http://troy.jdmz.net/rsync/index.html
- http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/209